# Android : Function to delete a sentence in a EditText

Tags: java, android

I have a EditText and near to it I have a button with the cross.

What I want is to know the Function to put in my `ButtonX.setOnclickListener` to clear the EditText !!

is that something like `setClear()` or something ?

Thank you !

Comment: `editText.setText("");`

Comment: Take a look at the `setText` method.

Comment: Ok thank you I was expecting a function like Clear() or something ! 
Thx again !

Comment: @Nemka First thing you should do : look at the doc and see what method of the API can help you to achieve what you want ! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html =)

Comment: Duplocate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308200/clear-text-in-edittext-when-entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
//inside onClick
yourEditText.setText("");
```

doing this, you set a empty text