# Android Edit field: how to Clear text immediately on click?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I follow this guide to clear edit field when enter
[Clear text in EditText when entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308200/clear-text-in-edittext-when-entered)

But I have to **click 2 times** for clearing the edit field.

Here is the code:

```
public class Trackfolio extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    public EditText editText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        editText.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        editText.setText("");
    }

}
```

My question is **how to clear the edit text in only one click?**

I really appreciate your helps. Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: Are your sure about your issue ? . The provided code will work with single button click . . .

Comment: I don't think your question is valid. Just check your code properly.

Comment: i really don't believe in down vote, as some question naive to someone is hard for other to get

Comment: @MD Actually my problem caused by `OnFocusable`, I must implement `OnFocusChangeListener` instead of `OnClickListener`. I'm really disappointed because you even do not make any help but vote me down.

Comment: I had the same problem, thanks for pointing me to OnFocusChangeListener

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
editText.getText().clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    editText.setFocusable(true);
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.editText1:
         editText.setText("");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

  }

}
```

i think this will solve your problem let me know if it won't

Comment: Thank you my bro. I figure out how to solve my problem by implement `OnFocusChangeListener`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add two more attributes in your `EditText` xml `focusale` & `clickable`

```
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you my bro. I figure out how to solve my problem by implement `OnFocusChangeListener`. :)